# enable php extensions via composer

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, composer-php

I have an EC2 instance in AWS but I don't have an access to it.

I found a way in the internet and I test it but nothing worth to mention. it didn't work.

So this is what I've had in the composer.

```
 "require": {

    "ext-gd": "*",
    "ext-intl": "*"


}
```

Is there anyway to enable `PHP_intl` through the composer? If yes, what will be changed in `composer.lock`?

Comment: Did you run `composer update` to update your json?

Comment: @SaadSuri yes but I compare the composer.lock with the newer one I cans see any changes in the file except the packages

Comment: Composer can only manage which extensions are required by a package, it can't actually install or enable them if they aren't present.

Comment: @iainn maybe this is my case, is there any way that might solve this issue?

Comment: Well not with Composer. If you need to enable extensions, you'll need to have access to the server (or someone who does).